# Is there a way to get Spotlight to search for xattr?

Tags: macos, spotlight, extended-attributes

I like to tag files with xattr, e.g. `xattr -w user.foo bar myfile`.

**Is there a way that I can then use Spotlight to search for a given xattr key (or key-value pair)?** For example, if I put `foo` or `foo:bar` in the Spotlight search bar, I'd like it to return `myfile` in the result list.

I realize you can do this by writing the `com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags` attribute - but this is not very portable, so I'm curious if this can be extended to all xattr tags.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on [this](https://eclecticlight.co/2018/01/08/spotlight-using-metadata-to-improve-local-searches/), yes but you are limited to using com.apple attributes. As for extending Spotlight to any xattrib tags, [you could](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/MDImporters/Concepts/WritingAnImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001275-208147) but you will need to develop an importer for Spotlight. There are plenty of metadata tags available, I would pick one to be used as a personal tag.

If committed to searching by custom xattrib, I would give up on Spotlight and use:

```
find . -xattrname foo
```

Comment: The second link is for Carbon - do you know if this is supported in Cocoa?

Comment: I do not develop for macOS, but my understanding is Carbon uses pure C and Cocoa uses an objective-C API easily accessible to C or C++. The link definitely has objective-C examples.

Comment: I have developed a few Spotlight plug-ins and they can be written mostly in Objective-C. Some C is needed to set up the plug-in but this is provided by Xcode's project template.